# Прозрачное окно в opencv

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, opencv, pyside2

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог выводить только `rectangle`, при этом чтобы всё остальное было полностью прозрачным - **по настоящему прозрачным**.

Вот код:

```
    while True:
    img = p_out.recv()

    for (x,y,w,h) in t1.detectMultiScale(img, ais, ain):
        p_in2.send(np.asarray([x,y,w,h]))
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Vision", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0 == 1:
        break
```

**P.S.** На то как я получаю `img` не смотрите, это просто попытка сделать фон прозрачным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.title = QLabel('<h1 style="color: red;">Title Bar</h1>' ) 
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        btn_size = 35
        self.btn_close = QPushButton("x")
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_close.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.btn_min = QPushButton("_")
        self.btn_min.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_min.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")
        self.btn_max = QPushButton("+")
        self.btn_max.setFixedSize(btn_size, btn_size)
        self.btn_max.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;")

        self.line = QFrame(self)
        self.line.setStyleSheet("border: 3px solid rgb(255, 205, 0);")
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        
        title_bar = QHBoxLayout()
        title_bar.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)        
        title_bar.addWidget(self.title)
        title_bar.addWidget(self.btn_min)
        title_bar.addWidget(self.btn_max)
        title_bar.addWidget(self.btn_close)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)   
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)        
        main_layout.addLayout(title_bar)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.line)   
        main_layout.addStretch()                                   
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  # QMainWindow  -QWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.widget = Widget(self)
        self.widget.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.btn_close_clicked)
        self.widget.btn_min.clicked.connect(self.btn_min_clicked)
        self.widget.btn_max.clicked.connect(self.btn_max_clicked)
        
        lbl = QLabel('Hello World !!', self, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
        lbl.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                font-family: 'Consolas'; 
                color: red; 
                font-size: 55px;
            }
        """)
        
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True )   
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            MainWindow {
                background-color: rgba(0, 215, 55,    0);
/*  попробуйте заменить строку выше на:              v^ <---
                background-color: rgba(0, 215, 55,   70);
*/                
                border: 3px solid rgb(255, 205, 0);
            }
        """) 

        self.button = QPushButton("Quit", self)
        self.button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, 
                              x1:0.988818, y1:0.915, 
                              x2:0, y2:0, 
                              stop:0 rgba(53, 129, 90, 255), 
                              stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
            font: 75 16pt \"Georgia\";
        """)
        
        self.button.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        layout.addWidget(lbl)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
    def btn_close_clicked(self):
        quit()

    def btn_min_clicked(self):
        self.showMinimized() 

    def btn_max_clicked(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
            self.widget.btn_max.setText('+')
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
            self.widget.btn_max.setText('R')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
        self.old_width = self.width()
        self.old_height = self.height()
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton):                
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.old_Pos)
            if (self.old_Pos.x() > self.x() + self.old_width - 10) or \
               (self.old_Pos.y() > self.y() + self.old_height - 10):
                w = self.old_width+delta.x()  if self.old_width+delta.x()  > 230 else 230
                h = self.old_height+delta.y() if self.old_height+delta.y() >  85 else  85 
                self.setFixedSize(w, h)                   
            else:
                self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
                self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

*Я не нашёл как сделать прозрачное окно на cv2*

*Вот альтернатива*

```
import sys
import numpy
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette, QBrush, QImage
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageQt


# Отловить ошибки в слотах PyQt5
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class TransparentWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.interface()
    def interface(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        pil_image = Image.new('RGBA', (300, 300), (0, 0, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
        draw.rectangle((0, 0, 300, 300), outline=(0, 0, 255), width=5)

        numpy_array = numpy.array(pil_image)
        opencv_image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_array, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)# cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV

        # Start coordinate, here (5, 5)
        # represents the top left corner of rectangle
        start_point = (5, 5)

        # Ending coordinate, here (220, 220)
        # represents the bottom right corner of rectangle
        end_point = (220, 220)

        # Blue color in BGRA
        color = (0, 0, 255, 255)

        # Line thickness of 2 px
        thickness = 2

        # Using cv2.rectangle() method
        # Draw a rectangle with blue line borders of thickness of 2 px
        image = cv2.rectangle(opencv_image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)


        # Конвертируем изображение из OpenCV в PIL
        pil_image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA))

        image_qt = ImageQt.toqimage(pil_image)

        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image_qt)

        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Normal, QPalette.Window, QBrush(pixmap))
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Window, QBrush(pixmap))

        self.setPalette(palette)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())

    def drag_window(self, event):
        delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.old_position)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.old_position = event.globalPos()
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Выбрать окно при помощи мыши"""
        self.old_position = event.globalPos()
        self.old_position = event.globalPos()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """Переместить окно с помощью мыши"""
        self.drag_window(event)
        x, y = self.get_window_coordinates()
        width, height = self.get_window_size()
        region = x, y, width, height
    def get_window_size(self):
        """Вернёт кортеж(width, height) размер окна"""
        size = self.frameSize().width(), self.frameSize().height()
        return size
    def get_window_coordinates(self):
        """Вернёт кортеж(x, y) координаты окна"""
        coordinates = self.x(), self.y()
        return coordinates


def main():
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    transparent_window = TransparentWindow()
    transparent_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант через прозрачный фон

```py
import sys
from typing import List

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QPaintEvent, QPen
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, _: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        g = QPainter(self)

        rc = self.rect()
        g.fillRect(rc, Qt.transparent)

        fg = QPen()
        fg.setColor(Qt.red)
        fg.setWidth(5)

        g.setPen(fg)
        g.drawRect(rc)


def main(args: List[str]) -> int:
    app = QApplication(args)

    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Демо(ОС: Debian testing):

> [image: pyside2 transparent window]

**UPD**: этот способ не работает в Windows

[image: test in windows]

Comment: Не работает, черный фон вместо того что у вас прозрачное. Но да, на видео то что мне нужно! [ссылка](https://ibb.co/gjFLnJr)